# How to get a variable back in 'except' block, which is already assigned in 'try' block, in a 'try-except' statement in Python

Tags: python, function, exception, optional-parameters

The question is :
*Write a function called 'root' that is given a number x and an integer n and returns x^(1\n). In the function definition, set the default value of n to 2*

Now I want to create the function *root(x,n)* where 'n' is optional. If the user merely entered the value of 'x' and pressed 'Enter', the function must return the value of '*x^(0.5)*'

I tried taking multiple inputs using split() in a try block in an attempt to skip the ValueError in except block

**The code :**

> ```
> def root(base,exp=2) :   
>
>     return base**(1/exp)
>
> try :
>
>     x,n=input("Enter the base and nth_root :").split()
>
>     x,n=int(x),int(n)
>
> except ValueError :  
>
>     print("By default, power is 0.5")
>
> print(root(x,n))
> ```

This works perfectly when I give both the values 'x' and 'n'
But when I give only one input i.e. 'x' and press 'Enter' , the print statement in except block gets printed but I see :
'*NameError: name 'x' is not defined*'

Is there any possible way to get the value of 'x',that is taken from the user in 'try' block, back in 'except' block?
I expect the value of 'x' to retain from 'try' block to 'except' block, so that the function *root(x,n)*  will return *x^(0.5)*

Comment: First off, it *wasn't* assigned. Second, even if it was, `n` wouldn't have been assigned, so you'd just get a `NameError` for `n` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `x` and `n` on separate lines.  And give `n` a default value before the input, so it will exist even if there is an error.

```
n = 0.5 # assume default
try :
    answer = input("Enter the base and nth_root :").split()
    x = answer[0]
    x = int(x)
    n = answer[1]
    n = int(n)
except ValueError :  
    print("By default, power is 0.5")
print(root(x,n))
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght Not sure what you're asking.  Where, exactly, would the `else` be, and what would it do?